# Need to build apk from sencha touch 2.4.1

Tags: extjs, build, apk, touch

I am trying to build apk after doing some changes in my existing app.
My app is in **sencha touch 2.4.1**. previously we build in the **phonegap**.

Phonegap is not available, is there any alternative to build apk.

We did not found any solution to build the app, yet.

Answer (score 1):

The Sencha Touch documentation provides instructions on how to utilize Cordova to create an APK file: https://docs-devel.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/tutorials/cordova_camera.html

Alternatively, you could generate a Cordova application and then copy your build folder into the "www" directory. After doing so, you would need to update the XML file to point to the application's index.html file.

For more information on getting started with Cordova, please refer to the official documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted